# Side by side blogging?

Tags: customization

I'm designing a blog with wordpress as my CMS. My client would like one page on the site to have two main content areas, each with a title above and streaming posts from different categories.

So far I haven't seen any examples of this anywhere on the web. Is this possible to do? If so, whats the best approach?

Answer (score 1):

See If this helps. Bill Erickson has a great tutorial on how to use multiple content areas in thesis theme. I think you should be able to replicate it with any good WP Theme.

Here is the [link](http://www.billerickson.net/wordpress-thesis-multiple-content-areas/)

Answer (score 0):

This is where you want to be looking.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query

I have used this method before on my site to display 1 category at the top for featured posts and then another to display the main loop.

```
<?php $featured = new WP_Query('category_name=Featured&showposts=1');
    while ($featured->have_posts()) : $featured->the_post();
    $do_not_duplicate = $post->ID; ?>
```

As you can see I selected my category and for this example I only wanted to display one post. Hope this helps.